# custom styling broken after upded to v4

Tags: material-ui

After update from v3 to v4.8.3 do not work customizing components. My goal is to override Select component to get text color 'red'.

```
const styles = theme => ({ temp: { fontSize: 12, color: "red" })
```

...

```
<Select classes={{ root: classes.temp }} ....> ...</Select>
```

but MuiInputBase-input class always stay on top.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjPMp.png

I see that there are diffrents in styles loading by html head import, my current version(v4) is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA6Gy.png

I see that import  is doubled, and overrides my custom style.
On v3 all mui styles imports was placed on top of list and not mixed vs custom styles. I cant find more info to get solution and reason of doubling imports. where error may arise?

**edit:**

i must give some more details...

Problem appered after a big legacy project was updated. For represet my problem, i cut most of code and create demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-hdmi3) . 
Unfortunately it work fine on codesandbox, and dont let see a problem.  if i download zip and start it - i have my problem. Tried on two machine ubuntu 18.04 and MacOS, both have that problem - colour red dont applied to second select. Some more detail are in [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19344) if it will helpfull for someone. Reason in solution below

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in the console about having more than one copy of `@material-ui/styles`?

Comment: no, there are nothing like that. But in the end of parent component, there is 
  component: <InputBase type="file"...> .... </inputBase>.  If i drop that one, doubled import will clear and custom style work as well

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: Here is the problem reproduced in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions59826868custom-styling-broken-after-upded-to-v4-c1io6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-hdmi3) work fine. But downloaded zip have problem. On two machine ubuntu 18.04 and MacOS,  both have that problem - colour dont applied to second select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that nested component has wrong import statement. Wrong import that was work "properly" in v3 for some reason:

```
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase/InputBase";
```

must be:

```
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
```

becouse it, my styles was overriding by base style

Answer (score 0):

I have created sandbox for you where you can see the overwritten menu items.

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-c1io6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I just created demo https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-hdmi3 , and in codesandbox its work fine. But when i dowload zip to my machine and start that, second select dont get red color. it seems like i have a problem on my machine, like broken npm cache or something like that...

Comment: just tested downloaded zip from [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-hdmi3) on two machine ubuntu 18.04 and MacOS, and both have that problem - colour dont applied to second select